# Hyperledger Fabric invokeChaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

I want to invoke another chaincode inside a chaincode using ctx.stub.invokeChaincode("called chaincode name", ["the name of the function (transaction) of the called chaincode", args]), and my both chaincodes has been instantiated on the same channel, but I get the following error:

> Calling chaincode Invoke() returned error response [Error: You've
>   asked to invoke a function that does not exist: Confirm.confirmData].
>   Sending ERROR message back to peer.

I am not sure if I am wrong with defining the list chainCode arguments.

Comment: Seem that your function name is wrong. Check if the function name it's similar to the chaincode function name.

Comment: No, the function name is the same as I defined in my invoked chaincode.

Comment: @ethertest I hope you have been following these [considerations](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/developapps/chaincodenamespace.html#considerations) for cross chaincode interactions